# Laravel html/collective value loaded in dropdown

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravelcollective

i have a problem with loading in a value from the database related to an htmlcollective dropdown. i have tried some solutions but none of them worked. 
the only thing the dropdown has to do is read out the category i've placed the article in and remember it. i want it to not be the default value, so when category 5 is used for the article, i want it to select category 5 automatically.
**Controller:**

```
public function edit(Request $request, $id)
{
    return view('artikelen.edit',[
        'categories' => Categorie::pluck('naam', 'id')->toArray(),
        'artikel' => Artikel::find($id)
    ]);
}
```

**edit.blade.php:**

```
<div class="form-group bold">
        {{Form::label('category_id', 'Categorie')}}
        <br>

        {{Form::select('category_id', $categories, )}}

    </div>
```

can anyone spot what i did wrong? 
any help would be appreciated thanks,

Comment: do you want to retrieve all articles based on category?is that what u mean?

Comment: okay i'll try to explain, i have an newswebsite. and when i want to edit an article, i want the category dropdown to be the value which is equal to the category of the article.

Comment: Which `Form` are you using?

Comment: an html collective form for laravel

Comment: {!! Form::open(['action' => 'ArtikelController@update', 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}

Comment: ` {{Form::select('category_id', $categories, $artikel->category_id)}}' The third parameter is select value

Comment: `{{Form::select('category_id', $categories, request()->get('category_id'))}}` You can replace `category_id` with your category variable.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud and Ajay, you both have given good working solutions. create a answer and i will give it the checkmark